# Вывод содержимого базы данных с помощью Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

Имеется база данных postgresql с пятью таблицами. Основная задача связана с выводом данных из таблиц на страницу HTML. Например, мне нужно вывести данные из таблицы Artists. Создаю модель данной таблицы:

```
class Artists(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
date_of_start = models.DateField()
date_of_end = models.DateField()
```

Далее пытаюсь вытащить значения полей таблицы следующим образом:

```
<body>
{% for i in Artists %}
    <tr class='success'>
        <td>{{ i.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ i.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ i.date_of_start }}</td>
        <td>{{ i.date_of_end }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Получаю пустую страницу. При этом сама таблица данными заполнена.

Comment: А вы передали переменную `Artists` в шаблон? Если нет, то знайте, что переменные в шаблоне сами по себе из ниоткуда не появляются

Comment: Что значит «сама таблица данными заполнена»? Какая таблица и где?

Comment: Таблицы базы данных сгенерированы с помощью data modeler. Строки таблиц заполнены данными. А что по поводу шаблона?

Comment: По поводу шаблона почитайте в учебниках, как их вообще правильно использовать и как им передавать переменные

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**models.py**

```
class Artists(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    date_of_start = models.DateField()
    date_of_end = models.DateField()
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

# импорт модели Artists

class ArtistView(ListView):
    model = Artists
    template_name = 'имя_вашего_шаблона.html'
    context_object_name = 'artists'
```

**template**

```
{% for artist in artists %}
    <tr class='success'>
        <td>{{ artist.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ artist.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ artist.date_of_start }}</td>
        <td>{{ artist.date_of_end }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```